# Problem matching strings with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble matching strings in MySQL. I have the following:

```
SELECT ea.* 
FROM epf_application ea 
    JOIN epf_application_device_type ead ON ea.application_id = ead.application_id
    JOIN epf_device_type edt ON ead.device_type_id = edt.device_type_id 
WHERE 
    edt.name = 'someDevice'
LIMIT 30
```

I would like to filter the above results even further by adding `ea.title='%tele%'` to the above sql statement like the following

```
SELECT ea.* 
FROM epf_application ea 
    JOIN epf_application_device_type ead ON ea.application_id = ead.application_id
    JOIN epf_device_type edt ON ead.device_type_id = edt.device_type_id 
WHERE 
    edt.name = 'someDevice' AND ea.title='%tele%'
LIMIT 30
```

The above sql statement doesn't return anything, however when I do the following I get a result.

```
SELECT ea.* 
FROM epf_application ea 
    JOIN epf_application_device_type ead ON ea.application_id = ead.application_id
    JOIN epf_device_type edt ON ead.device_type_id = edt.device_type_id 
WHERE 
    edt.name = 'someDevice' AND ea.title='television'
LIMIT 30
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
ea.title LIKE '%tele%'
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `LIKE`

```
ea.title LIKE '%tele%'
```